# Filter measure by segmented dates, partially ignoring date heriarchy in table (Calculate Inflation)

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I am trying to calculate sales adjusted by monthly inflation, but taking the base month as the first one in the slicer.

[image]

In this case, I´d need X - FirstDate to be 1/3/2020 for every month that´s listed, so that the ProductX can be between the first and the last date. I can´t find the way to make this measure happen, any help would be appreciated!

For the FirstDate measure i have tried `CALCULATE(FIRSTDATE(Calendario[Date]);all(Calendario[Date]))`

but it still shows me the first date of each month. I either get that, or the first date of the whole calendar, ignoring the slicer that´s being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with your row context. It looks like your **Etiquetas de fila** is a hierarchy of **Year**, **Month number**, and I'm assuming **Date**.

This **Date** field, which is in the rows, is also the same field you are using in your slicer. So they are bound to be the same.

A quick workaround I would use is to create a second date column (simply duplicate your date column in the query), I'll name it **Date 2** for simplicity.

Then use **Date 2** as your slicer.

And your measure can simply be:
**CALCULATE ( MIN ( Table[Date] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Table, Table[Date 2] ) )**

This will return the minimum date in the whole table, filtered only by your slicer on **Date 2**

Hope that makes sense.